# How to prevent a UIView from consuming user input

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-input

I have a simple view hierarchy example.

[image]

Obviously the main view space is the primary space the user will interact with.  At the bottom I have tabs that can pop up to indicate to the user where he/she is in the progression of the app.  Normally, these tabs only take up the space indicated by the "Custom Tabs" rectangle at the bottom, but they can expand all the way up to fill the "Empty Space" box.

In order for the tabs to still be clickable, I had to make the tab view's frame the full rectangle containing both the "Custom Tabs" space and "Empty Space" space.  What this results in is that "Empty Space" not being interactive to the user when the tabs aren't popped up, because the input is basically being consumed by that UIView, and not forwarded through the rest of the hierarchy.

I suppose the root of this problem is that both "Main View Space" and the "Empty Space + Custom Tabs" are both subviews of the main window.

Is there a way I can tell the system to forward the user input to the sibling views if the user didn't actively tap on an interactive element?  For example, doing something with the `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded` etc. methods that would indicate to the OS that this view did not use the input.

**EDIT**

Here's another version of the view, demonstrating the tate of one tab being open:

[image]

**EDIT2**

After some simple testing, it would seem that the default behavior is that the top most view gets the input first.  This applies even if you have a clear `UIView` on top of a `UITextField`.  The clear `UIView` will consume the input, preventing the `UITextField` from being editable

**EDIT3**

The way the tabs are supposed to work is the user can tap on a tab (sized as in the first picture), and then it will expand to display a thumbnail view associated with that tab (as in the second picture).  The user can then optionally tap the tab once more to close it, and return the size to the original picture.  In order for the tab to be clickable when it is open, I have to have the containing view be basically large enough to contain all 4 tabs as if they were open.  This results in a lot of empty space in the containing view.  This empty space results in essentially dead input space on the screen.  If there were a button in the main view space that is covered by the empty space, the user would not be able to click on it. I would like to be able to avoid that behavior, and have that button covered by the empty space still be clickable.

Comment: Why don't you have just one view added to the window, and then you add  different subviews to that one?

Comment: what kind of class does represent the `CustomTabs` and the `EmptySpace` objects?

Comment: @holex `CustomTabs` and `EmptySpace` are just sections of a single `UIView` subclass

Comment: @frowing How do I initialize the views (presumably in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) so that both the main view space (the root view controller) and the custom tabs at the bottom are added to this new "Root view"?

Comment: Add the custom tabs view to the root view controller's view

Comment: @frowing I just tried that, and it still has the input problem

Comment: Well, then that one shouldn't change. Have another view controller as a child of the root view controller, making that one change.

Comment: in that case, please, try to replace the `UIView` class to `UIControl` class and you can handle every event and user interaction  from the user easily after.

Comment: @holex How would I ignore the input as a `UIControl` if it isn't on a particular element?

Comment: The key here I think is that both views are added to the window and the window only redirects input to one of them. You need to get rid of that.

Comment: @frowing  I added some more details in an edit to my post

Comment: @DanF maybe I misunderstood your question. I've read your question twice again and now I'm not sure what you exactly like to reach. your only one question is not your main problem, I guess. **What exactly do you like to do on the user interface with the tabs? What kind of behaviour of UI is being preferred by you? Could you specify your final goal?**

Comment: @holex I added some more explanation to the question, perhaps that will clarify my goal?

Comment: I think you should forget the `EmptySpace` object, and you should be working only the individual tabs. in that case, every tab would have two different states: the open and the close one. you could manage and store the current state of the tabs: when the user tap one of them and if it is open, you will close it and vicaversa. I don't know what is the functionality of the tabs (provides more information only or they have more UI element for more interaction with the user) so, I don't see the reason yet why you haven't done it this way... you could keep the room clean for the main space.

Comment: @holex I originally had them separate, but wanted to wrap them in another object so that I could more easily create and manage sets of tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to "forward" touches, I would modify your layout so that the tab view is only as big as the tabs, and change it's `.frame` to be the larger rectangle in code only when you need it.  For example, when a tab is clicked:

```
 CGRect tabFrame = tabView.bounds;
 tabFrame.origin.y = top_of_emptySpace;
 tabFrame.size.height = height_of_emptySpace + height_of_tabView;
 tabView.frame = tabFrame;
```

then you can add the content you need. when you need it to go away, remove the content then do :

```
 CGRect tabFrame = tabView.bounds;
 tabFrame.origin.y = top_of_tabView;
 tabFrame.size.height = height_of_tabView;
 tabView.frame = tabFrame;
```

There might be some tweaking required to make the content show up as you like, but this way, when the tabs are minimized, you won't have to do anything extra to make the main view respond to touches correctly.

Comment: There are multiple tabs, so when one is present, there would still be the problem of dead space

Comment: Then do the same thing but change the `.origin.x` and `.size.width` to exactly what you need

Comment: If I change the origin, then the whole view moves

Comment: are the tabs lying on a view? or do you only have one view?

Comment: There is a `TabController` that is one `UIView`.  It has 4 subviews that are individual `Tab`s

Comment: You could make a new view for the new content completely instead of trying to modify the existing one as well. `UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:desiredFrame];` then `[mainView addSubview:contentView];` then when you're done `[contentView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Not entirely the solution I was hoping to find, but it seems, for now, that the only solution is to create a separate view for the expanded tab

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the way I would do it:

The RootViewController has two views, its main view which takes the whole screen, the one that is added to the window. And the tab view.

Then I would add another view controller (a UINavigationController ideally) to the RootViewController and I would have its view added as a subview of the RootViewController's view.

Any change performed, such as pushing new view controller or anything, would be done to the child view controller.

That way, your tab view would always be showing. To open a tab, you could create a new view that would show on top of the tab bar using an animation or something similar.

Comment: I have tried that.  My setup right now is root view controller is a splitview, whose primary detail view is a navigation controller.  I added the tabs to the split view controller's view, and I run into the same problem