# Button stretching bug

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have these tabs that the user can tap on and expand.  As I decided was the correct way to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524440/how-to-prevent-a-uiview-from-consuming-user-input) problem, I am removing the tabs from the containing view and adding them to the window when they expand.  This seems to have resulted in a very strange bug: the texture for the normal state of the button is suddenly being stretched after the tab has been opened.

**Before**

[image: tabs all appear normal]

**After**

[image: first tab has been opened and closed, showing stretched texture]

I have done some relatively extensive logging, showing that before and after the open and close animations, the frame for the entire tab, and its enclosed button are exactly the same:

```
2012-07-31 10:08:33.835 Project[1937:1c103] Button:{{0, 0}, {133, 25}}
2012-07-31 10:08:33.836 Project[1937:1c103] Tab:{{0, 177.333}, {133, 25}}
2012-07-31 10:08:34.340 Project[1937:1c103] Tab done:{{118, 777.5}, {133, 202.5}}
2012-07-31 10:08:34.341 Project[1937:1c103] Button done:{{0, 0}, {133, 25}}
```

This issue **ONLY** occurs if I remove the tab from its containing view and add it to the window instead.  If I animate the tab within its containing view, the texture does not get messed up.

I'm at a total loss here.

Here is the code where I create the tab texture and button:

```
tabImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_stretchable"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 25, 15)];
CGRect tabFrame = frame;
tabFrame.origin.x = 0;
tabFrame.origin.y = 0;
tabButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:tabFrame];
[tabButton setBackgroundImage:tabImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tabButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tabPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:tabButton];
```

`frame` at this point is `{{0, 177.333}, {133, 25}}`

**EDIT**

Also, the texture for when the button is being pressed on remains normal, it is only the "normal" state of the button that has a messed up texture.

**EDIT2**

Here is al ink to a git repository of a basic example that still reproduces my problem:

https://github.com/starphoenix/TabBug2.git

Comment: Two comments - if you are removing gui elements and adding them to another view during animations nasty things can happen. In any case, if you can spin a simple project that shows this, then put it on github or DropBox (as a zip), then I and others could take a crack at looking for the issue.

Comment: @DavidH Understandable to avoid moving views around in the middle of the animation, but I move the view THEN trigger the animation

Comment: I just get the feeling that something is changing as the window is rendering the view. It would be easier to play with code than trying to figure out this. Given your point score you are no amateur :-) - so if you can't find it will be hard for other mere mortals to find. That said sometimes having people take a fresh look at something will result in progress.

Comment: Another idea - after you move the view to the window, issue a dispatch_async on the main queue with [tabView setNeedsDisplay], and see if anything changes.

Comment: @DavidH I added a link to a git in the question that has my problem

Comment: Great! Will look at it later today!

Comment: Yikes - its missing the png - can you add it to the project?

Comment: @DavidH Sorry, its there now.

Comment: So I have the project - it shows on tab top left of a small box on a white background. It looks just fine in the simulator. What do I need to do to get the problem to show?

Comment: @DavidH When you tap on the button it executes the same code I have in my project, it performs a meaningless animation and swaps it between being contained within the window, and in the sub view

Comment: try your own code - there is no button - not on my system. I see an iPad portrait screen, white background, black box with white tab in it. Thats it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14710/discussion-between-dan-f-and-david-h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further testing, the issue appears to only be with my simulator.  The bug does not appear on an actual device

Answer (score 0):

So let me take a stab at this. The user taps the tab, which is a custom button. The button then highlights. While the button is midway through this operation it gets yanked from one view and placed into another.

So at first blush, what I would suggest is that you not yank one button out of a view and add it to the window while there is any chance of highlighting going on, but animate the opacity of the old button to 0, and add a new button where you want it configured the same as the old one. So you would constantly be creating new buttons and animating out (and then discarding) the old buttons.